# Create Fragment with Class Object

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

We can do that:

```
val fragment = SomeFragment()
val args = Bundle()
args.putString("Key_Value", "String_Value")
fragment.arguments = args
```

And we can take it from Fragment like this:

```
arguments.getString("String_key","Default Value")
```

My question is can we pass a class object as parameter?

```
val some_object = SomeClass()
args.put("Key_Value", some_object )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass something that's parcelable (Don't do this with classes like Activities, Fragments etc. )
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649155/7968986

Or pass something that identifies that class, for example it's possible to pass the Classname as a String and then inside the fragment call stuff like startActivity if it's a Activity / Android related class that you shouldn't pass (or parcelize)

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676049/7968986

In general the class is not allowed to be too big if it's parcelized, so in some cases you need other solutions

Comment: First one (with Parcelable) is did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help